# Present/create view controllers with swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have `UIViewController` with fabric method "create with index".

What I want to build is just like photo gallery in iPhone, you swipe left - you create view controller with index -1, you swipe right, you create another controller with index +1.

I used `UIPageViewController` for that, but for some reason it show me wrong page after certain swipes, and I cant figure out why.

What my outcome is, I just want to use **Swipe Gesture** to create my controllers with swipes.

But, I need animation, like when you scroll one page left or right, so, you can see with animation how new controller is presented, and show "old" controller in animation time. Now i use:

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Do what you want here
    NSLog(@"did swiped left");
    [CalendarViewController createNext:-1];
    [self presentViewController:[CalendarViewController createNext:-1] animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Do what you want here
    NSLog(@"did swiped right");
    [CalendarViewController createNext:[CalendarViewController createNext:1]];
    [self presentViewController:[CalendarViewController createNext:1] animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Is there any way to achieve animation, like when you swipe photo in gallery left or right? Now it look like modally presented new vc.

Comment: you can add child view controller and add subview when swipe !!

Comment: Good idea brother:-)why don not you try to set images in scroll view?

Comment: @MikeAlter what animation i need for it?

Comment: @user3182143 its not views, its view controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add effect as you mentioned in question then you have to add two swipe gesture recognizer for detection of left swipes and right swipes.

You should have configure your own transition effect which presents your `viewcontroller` like push or pop effect. You can achieve it by following,

For presenting `View Controller` (swipe from right to left),

```
CATransition *customTransition = [CATransition animation];
customTransition.duration = 0.3;
customTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
customTransition.type = kCATransitionPush;
customTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:customTransition forKey:nil];

[self presentViewController:yourViewControllerToBePresent animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For Dismissing View Controller(swipe from left to right i assume!),

```
  CATransition *customTransitionDismiss = [CATransition animation];
customTransitionDismiss.duration = 0.3;
customTransitionDismiss.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
customTransitionDismiss.type = kCATransitionPush;
customTransitionDismiss.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:customTransitionDismiss forKey:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But this is not best approach i think.

If you have many pages then you should go with `UIPageViewController` or `UICollectionView` with single cell with `paging scroll effect` which will `deque` the cells and will be memory efficient!!

Comment: as i mention, i firstly use UIPageViewController, but somehow it return wrong page in rare cases, and my logic was correct.

Comment: have you try another approach? like collection view or custom transition that i have mentioned in answer?

Comment: have you test your code? It act weird, it swipes first but then appear like modal presentation.

Comment: i did try but i abandon that idea, because in my case every view its not just a view, but view controller, and there was problem presenting it like collection view single cell (because inside it was a view controller).

Comment: then i think pageviewcontroller is best option for you. try to figure out why it is showing wrong page in rare case. you must doing some mistake!!

Comment: thank you, but i doubt that there a mistake, you see,  i got different results each time i launch app, that mean there is somehow dependent on inner technique of how page view controller work, because in 12 different case it return 3 different controllers, 1 of them is correct though)

Answer (score 1):

try below code for left swipe use transition subtype kCATransitionFromLeft what you want

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        self.view.window!.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated:false, completion:nil)
```

Comment: im not using swift or storyboards, can you provide an example in obj-c?